# Remote Object request image change

Tags: apache-flex

I am using Flex with BlazeDS to connect a J2EE AppServer. Can I place any Global Image in any global position that would change automatically whenever any remote object is called and the image would be set as default whenever the response comes back from the server?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to implement some sort of a loading screen or interface widget. (Did you know you can set the showBusyCursor on a remote object instance?)

There is no way to globally intercept the method calls on your remote objects though. You'll need to solve this by either:

1. create a subclass of RemoteObject that sets some global flag on the result and fault events.
2. write the same result and fault event handling code on each remote object call that sets a global flag.

Option 1 is a bit more advanced but will save you the boilerplate code that option 2 has.